# Bounty on an answered question

Tags: support, bounty

I'm the OP of a question which, sadly, I hadn't accepted the answer for lack of attention. This weekend, someone offered a bounty on it just because the snippet of code in the answer had a small bug (wasn't checking the return of a function). If I accept the answer that didn't completely help the *Bounteer* (is this a word?), but helped me, will it ruin his bounty? What's the protocol here to deal with this situation? Do I wait his bounty to finish so I can accept the answer?

Comment: **Bounty Giver** seems to be the term everyone uses, I used to use *Bounty Awarder*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. Accepting an answer to a question and awarding a bounty are two different actions. One has no bearing on the other.<sup>1</sup> You can accept one answer and the bounty giver can award their bounty to a different answer, the same answer, or none of them. (Although in the latter case the automatic half-bounty award may come into play.)

There's no need for you wait for the bounty. There's also no need to accept an answer because you think you're supposed to. If the answer didn't solve your problem you shouldn't accept it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless you are both the Asker and the Bounty giver. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

*(h/t [Kendra](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2607247/kendra))*